The name MAX isn't recognized in my IF statement
I am trying to create a new column to set anyone from the current MAX date in my jSiteDate column to 7 days before it, so like 6/3/24 - 6/10/24. I am getting an error that I am unsure how to fix, here is a picture of my program MAX ERROR- can someone help me out?
I tried to re-write it a few different ways and always get the same result.

instead of creating a new custom column, can you please try with a measure?

I'm not sure how I would go about creating that as a measure - if you could give me an example?
I also tried putting in parenthesis in a few different spots, and it gives me the same error.

MAX is a DAX function, not a Power Query function. The equivalent in Power query is List.Max. Note that Power Query is case-sensitive.
However, a simple change from MAX[jSiteDate] to List.Max([jSiteDate]) won't get you what you expect since [jSiteDate] is not a column in this context but a single value.
This might work:
if [jSiteDate] <= List.Max(#"Sorted Rows1"[jSiteDate]) - 7 then "ACTIVE" else "NonActive"


Thank you! I think this would have worked, but I am in DirectQuery mode and it errors out until I swap it to import mode, which I can't do for this project. I will go back to the drawing board to figure out how to get this to filter my project.
